# How can I comment out the closing tag from a CDATA section for displaying in HTML?

Tags: jquery, regex, cdata

In dealing with some CDATA output from my CMS, I ran into the issue of removing the closing tag from being visible in the output:

```
var html = $(this).html();
html = html.replace("]]\&gt;", " ");
$(this).html(html);
```

Note: I struggled with this, so please be sure to escape the > character with a backslash \ character!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the the regex pattern syntax. It should look like:

```
html = html.replace(/\]\]\&gt;/g, " ");
```

or

```
html = html.replace(/]]\&gt;/g, " ");
```

You can check it out at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev,  I had tried the above suggestions, but was forgetting  to escape the > . Posted this in case it would help another.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the above code was run from jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){}
```